# Laravel: must be of the type array string given

Tags: laravel

I have incoming data from android application but I cannot access them in my query

`incoming data`

```
[1ad3c212-6b4d-4dc3-8ae4-41aa6b12ff93, bd82e93d-8860-4cd3-8151-ef2c2e677b7a, a4d79d92-b02a-4ee9-ac1e-475745c4cc33]
```

`usage`

```
 $servicesPrice = Service::whereIn('service_id', $request->input('selectedServices'))->sum('price');
```

`Error`

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, string given
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: it must be `["1ad3c212-6b4d-4dc3-8ae4-41aa6b12ff93","bd82e93d-8860-4cd3-8151-ef2c2e677b7a", "a4d79d92-b02a-4ee9-ac1e-475745c4cc33"]`  there is no number like this without `""` it should be string   you can validate from here https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @KamleshPaul how can I fix it?

Comment: tell android dev uuid is type of string to send string type inside array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a walk around here:

you can clear array braces and explode the string to array using ',' as separator:

```
$value=$request->input('selectedServices');
$value = str_replace(['[', ']'], null, $value);
$serviceIds= explode( ',',$value);
$servicesPrice = Service::whereIn('service_id', $serviceIds)->sum('price');
```